# Getting missing values between two tables

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, missing-data

I have *two tables* and I would like to know the count of missing rows (in this case number of people) missing from one of the tables.

The first table is the list of people who got a job offer
The second table is the list of people who actually joined the company and registered on companies HR system.

What I want to find out is the *percentage of people* joining/not joining after getting an offer..

using redshift

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider

> list of people who got a job offer - TABLE1
>
> list of people who actually joined - TABLE2
>
> Common column in both tables - CandidateId

### Query will be

```
Select (Count(*)* 100.0 / (Select Count(*) From TABLE1)) as Percentage
From TABLE1 where CandidateId NOT IN (SELECT CandidateId FROM TABLE2)
```

Comment: You may want to multiply by `100.0` to prevent integer division

Comment: you are dividing TABLE1.Count by TABLE1.Count - the first one should be TABLE2

Comment: @HansKeﬆing but dividing on condition